# phpbb specific forum page styles

Tags: php, javascript, coding-style, phpbb

I am using phpbb on a site for a client, and the client has requested that each different forum page have a different background color.

Such functionality is not built into phpbb (from what I can tell), so how should I go about doing this? Can I modify the code of phpbb directly?

My other thought was to use a js conditional statement, but seeing as the only difference on the forums page would be the page title, I don't know how I could format this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can include a js in a way that won't break when the software is updated then that would be preferable, using the forum id from the url perhaps?

Otherwise, this is a stab in the dark, but try this:

1. Find where phpbb outputs the <head>
2. Use a switch/case statement and output the necessary css based on the forum ids.
3. Document *exactly* where you made the changes, and remember that you may need to make them again when phpbb is updated to new versions.